# Dominio .com tem mais relevância que .tk para o google?

Tags: google, domínio

Eu gostaria de saber se um domínio `.com` (www.example.com) é mais relevante do que o domínio `.tk`(www.example.tk). Ou isso não têm importância para o Google?

Comment: Não posso perguntar isso aqui?

Comment: Penso que sua pergunta não esteja relacionada com programação. Obs: não negativei.

Comment: Posso remover se não se enquadrar aqui

Comment: Mas como têm haver com sites achei que poderia

Comment: Acredito que o @rubStackOverflow tem razão, pois a pergunta não se refere a programação. Achei importante responder porque esse mito existe até hoje e a resposta poderá servir de referência para outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida :)

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes +1 porque a pergunta é interessante, no entanto votei pra fechar porque parece não ser do escopo, no entanto mesmo fechando ela ainda será publica e ganhará pontos com ela talvez e ajudará outras pessoas, o fechamento é realmente apenas por ser off-topic, no entanto pode ser que mesmo votando ela ainda se mantenha aberta *"pela aceitação da comunidade como um bom assunto"*, pois mesmo que tenhamos um escopo ainda sim algumas perguntas off são aceitar "pela comunidade". :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não, não é mais relevante.

Conforme este [post (em inglês)](https://plus.google.com/+MattCutts/posts/4VaWg4TMM5F) de um dos engenheiros da equipe de qualidade de buscas  do Google, isso é um mito e o domínio de nível maior ([TLD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dom%C3%ADnio_de_topo)) não tem relevância na avaliação do site ou página.

Porém, se uma busca é feita, por exemplo, no Brasil, um TLD `.br` tem  mais chances de aparecer nas primeiras posições.

Segue um link que explica sobre os fatores de ranking:

[Google’s 200 Ranking Factors (em inglês)](http://backlinko.com/google-ranking-factors)

Comment: Porquê o negativo? Ajude comentando para ajudar o colega a entender o motivo, assim ele pode ajudar/resolver/editar/melhorar/positivar, ou talvez você esteja totalmente errado!

Answer (score 2):

De fato, extensões de domínio não interferem em um primeiro momento no ranking do Google. O que vale é a idade do site, reputação, backlinks e sobretudo o conteúdo.

No entanto, domínios .TK sofrem muito spam e abuses. São tratados como domínios "sujos". Há algum tempo, o Google penalizou todo o TLD .TK .

Ao invés de usar um .TK, recomenda-se usar um blogspot.com ou wordpress.com . A nivel de SEO tem muito mais efeito.